# Execute Function called from variable in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My code:

```
<li class="grid--col2of10" ng-repeat="button in buttons">
   <button ng-show="button.show" class="btn--action-{{button.color}} icon-{{button.icon}}" ng-click="{button.clickAction}">{{button.text}}</button>
</li>
```

My object:

```
var btns = {
    "back": {
      "color": "red",
      "clickAction": "prevStep",
      "icon": "left",
      "text": "Back"
    }, 
    "cancel": {
      "color": "red",
      "icon": "block",
      "text": "Cancel"
    },
    "clear": {
      "color": "blue",
      "icon": "cancel",
      "text": "Clear"
    },
    "save": {
      "color": "green",
      "icon": "download",
      "text": "Save"
    },
    "next": {
      "color": "green",
      "clickAction": "nextStep",
      "icon": "right-after",
      "text": "Save and Continue"
    }
  };
```

Is it possible to make `button.clickAction` a function that is executed in AngularJS?

The btns object is inside a directive, and the html is called using the directive `templateUrl` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I couldn't execute it in the HTML, but I made it work by calling the function in my directive object:

```
var btns = {
    "back": {
      "color": "red",
      "clickAction": function() { prevStep(); },
      "icon": "left",
      "text": "Back"
    }, 
    "cancel": {
      "color": "red",
      "icon": "block",
      "text": "Cancel"
    },
    "clear": {
      "color": "blue",
      "icon": "cancel",
      "text": "Clear"
    },
    "save": {
      "color": "green",
      "icon": "download",
      "text": "Save"
    },
    "next": {
      "color": "green",
      "clickAction": function() { nextStep(); },
      "icon": "right-after",
      "text": "Save and Continue"
    }
  };
```

And the HTML:

```
<li class="grid--col2of10" ng-repeat="button in buttons">
   <button ng-show="button.show" class="btn--action-{{button.color}} icon-{{button.icon}}" ng-click="button.clickAction()">{{button.text}}</button>
</li>
```